# UIView is not moving with UIscrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I have added a view in IB. I have a label in this view, its height will vary at run time based on text it is holding, Now my question is when the label size is varying it is going beyond the height of UIView, So I want to add a scroll view in this view to view full label. I have added scroll view like this...

```
        CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
        UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
        CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                                  (self.view.frame.size.height + 1000));
        [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

After this scroll view is added in my view, however my view is not moving down when I scroll down. Am I doing anything wrong here...

thanks for your helps..

Comment: your scarollview fram hight not more then uiview so may be its happen try to CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
change height CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 560); or more

Comment: @NitinGohel I did tried, My scroll view is going down my view is not moving. :(

Comment: @Unknown I did like that only right? Can you tell more specific?

Comment: @Newbee have you tried setting the contentOffset?

Comment: @CStreel I did now. Its still the same. Is there any property we need to activate for self.view?

Comment: So you are after the code to auto scroll the view down so the user can see what is being created correct?

Comment: @CStreel No, View is not moving down, only scroll bar is moving down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this code..
first take `UIView` and add `UILable` in this your new view alike a bellow code .. like a flow..

```
    CGRect scrollViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    CGSize scrollViewContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                              (self.view.frame.size.height + 1000));
    [yourView addSubview:yourLable];
    [scrollView addSubview:yourView];
    [scrollView setContentSize:scrollViewContentSize];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

i hope this help you...

:)

Comment: That label I have added through IB. Do I need to add as subview again?

Comment: yes mate , here youwant to move view with scroolview then first add uiview and after add as a subview this lable.. :)

Comment: ok set frame as your self.view frame like this CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.view.frame; try this

Comment: also give Delegate in your .h file

Comment: No same self.view only I am adding. What Delegate?

Comment: Along with label I have one text view and a button in my view. All added through IB. If I add all programatically as subview as all mentioned, will it work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17911/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-newbee)

Answer (score 2):

If your scrollView is a subview of your view, then the view wouldn't move when you scroll the scrollView.  If you want the view to move when you scroll, it has to be vice-versa (the view has to be a subview of the scrollView). So for example, if you have a UIView with a UILabel that you need to scroll, the view heirarchy would be:

UIView (self.view) -> UIScrollView (scrollView) -> UIView -> UILabel

Alternatively, you don't really need a UIView to hold the UILabel so the UILabel could just be added as a subview of the UIScrollView.

The UIScrollView will only scroll content inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add your labelView to your ScrollView. From your code I can see that your scroll view is inside your view. Think of it like that:

You have a car (Your view) and you want it to scroll to you need to give it a road (ScrollView) that is longer then the car. What you are doing is putting the road inside the car when you should put the car inside the road.

Since you are using IB I beleive you should :

1. Add your ScrollView To your view (Your view won't move anywhere)
2. Add your labelView to the scrollView and set the scrollView height to your labelView final height.

An other option will be to add the scroll view in IB and add your view to your scrollview. The important thing is that your ScrollView Will be Road and your other views will be on the the road.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UITextView and add it as subview to your scrollview (scrollview is added to self.view):

```
// NSString *yourLabelString = (Your Label String)

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(320, 10000);
    CGSize size = [yourLabelString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    UITextView *yourTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    yourTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, size.width, size.height);
[scrollview addSubview:yourTextView];

scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size.width,size.height+20);
```